# in which cases will an EKF be better than the UKF?

Tags: kalman-filter

i have implemented an UKF lately, but comparing it to the EKF showed worse results than the EKF, while i was under the assumption this can never occure.

is that possible, and if so, under what circumstances?

thanks a lot, Joseph

Answer (score 0):

If the non-linearities of your system are quadractic (polynomial), then by applying the EKF up to the order of such polynomial you will have a closed and optimal analytical solution, you cannot do it better than that.

If you have other non-linearities, then it depends. If they are close to quadractic ones, then go for EKF, otherwise UKF. But this will depend mostly on your actual system, operation point, etc. It is not easy to tell in a such case.